# PHP Expire cookie

Tags: php, html, mysql, cookies

I am new to cookies and looking to make this cookie expire on my logout page

Here is where I set the cookie:

```
   setcookie("loggood", "YES", $expire, "/", "", 0);  
    setcookie("user", $pid, $expire, "/", "", 0);
```

Can anyone help me with how to make a cookie expire so the user can logout?

Thanks

Comment: You definitely don't want to save the logged in state in the cookies. They can be easily modified!

Comment: Store that state on the server (e.g. using PHP Sessions)! **Never ever** store such information at the client side!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete a cookie, then just set `$expire` time to be in the past:

```
setcookie("loggood", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie("user", "", time() - 3600);
```

Notes from [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> When deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is
> in the past, to trigger the removal mechanism in your browser.

Comment: Thanks, But for some reason when i add this code, i am still unable to logout? I remain logged in?

Comment: it's hard to predict what you are doing... maybe the issue is in something else.

Comment: I am using the code in my question to set the cookie, and then the code you have posted to end it?